# React Native Developer Menu on Huawei Mate 20 Pro

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, usb, huawei-mobile-services

How to open react-native developer menu on Huawei Mate 20 Pro (connected via USB)?

I run app by `react-native run-android`

Shaking and this is not working:

```
 adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Also i did:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: how are you running your application?

Comment: By command `react-native run-android`

Comment: are you by any chance using --variant=release ?

Comment: @CristianGomez Nope. I'm not using release version

Answer (score 0):

To access the developer menu, you can shake your device or select Shake Gesture in the Hardware menu in the iOS Simulator. Alternatively, you can use the ⌘D keyboard shortcut when your app is running in the iOS Simulator, or ⌘M when running in an Android emulator on Mac and Ctrl+M on Windows and Linux. For Android, you also can run the adb shell input keyevent 82 command to access the developer menu (in the command, 82 indicates the menu key-code).

[image]

Or, you can use that library (https://github.com/terrysahaidak/react-native-devmenu).

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/pie6k/react-native-dev-menu-on-touch

Open dev menu with 3 fingers touch in react native instead of shake gesture